# Car wont start 1994 Oldsmobile CutlussCiera

Tags: engine, starting, oldsmobile

I have a 1994 Oldsmobile Cutlass Ciera 3100. A person before me put in fuel pump and filter, timing chain, crank sensor,cam sensor, New starter.
Car still don't start. It cranks maybe 3 times and stops cranking, turn key off and it cranks 1 to two times and battery goes dead. Has New battery. Still won't start .
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: " it cranks 1 to two times and battery goes dead" maybe a bad battery? Replace the battery or charge it.